# How to change the value of 1 select if there are a lot of them on the page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to change the value of 1 select if there are a lot of them on the page.
I have 8 selects in table col and each of them must change separately.
I do not understand how to do this for each separately.
When I select opinion, all selects change the value.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

export default class Demo extends Component {
  state = {
    productTaxes: [
      { label: "Tax 8%", value: 10 },
      { label: "Tax 23%", value: 11 }
    ],
    selected: "10",
  };
  handleSelect = (e, key, type) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: e.target.value
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControl>
          <Select
            name={1}
            value={10}
            onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e, "tax")}
          >
            {this.state.productTaxes.map((tax, i) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={i} value={tax.value}>
                  {tax.label}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <Select
            name={2}
            value={this.state.selected}
            onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e, "tax")}
          >
            {this.state.productTaxes.map(tax => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={`tax${tax.value}`} value={tax.value}>
                  {tax.label}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need separate state for each select. You can use `name` attribute from `select`,

```
<Select
    name="select1"
    value={this.state.select1}
    onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e, "tax")}
>
  {this.state.productTaxes.map((tax, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem key={i} value={tax.value}>
            {tax.label}
        </MenuItem>
      );
  })}
</Select>
```

Same way you can do for all the selects.

And your `handleSelect` function should be,

```
handleSelect = (e, key, type) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};
```

---

**Note:** Avoid to use numbers for `name`, it is not good practice. Use more specific string names.

Another thing is, unless necessary don't pass extra parameters to function,

```
onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e, "tax")}
```

This can be simplified as,

```
onChange={this.handleSelect}
```

And your function can be,

```
handleSelect = (e) => { ... }
```

Also don't repeat the code. If you feel code is getting repeated, then you can always assign that part to a variable and use that variable instead,

```
render(){

  const options = this.state.productTaxes.map((tax, i) => {
       return (
          <MenuItem key={i} value={tax.value}>
              {tax.label}
          </MenuItem>
       );
  });

  return(
      ...
      <Select
        name="select1"
        value={this.state.select1}
        onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e, "tax")}
      >
        {options}
      </Select>
      ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from your demo, you're having just on property in your state. If you're changing the value of the first select, it will updated the state, which results in your second select having the same value.

For each select field you should have a different property in your state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save each select value independently. You can use the name tag for that like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

export default class Demo extends Component {
  state = {
    productTaxes: [
      { label: "Tax 8%", value: 10 },
      { label: "Tax 23%", value: 11 }
    ],
    1: "10",
    2: "10",
  };
  handleSelect = (e, key, type) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControl>
          <Select
            name={1}
            value={this.state[1]}
            onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e, "tax")}
          >
            {this.state.productTaxes.map((tax, i) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={i} value={tax.value}>
                  {tax.label}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <Select
            name={2}
            value={this.state[2]}
            onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e, "tax")}
          >
            {this.state.productTaxes.map(tax => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={`tax${tax.value}`} value={tax.value}>
                  {tax.label}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This will save each select value in the state independently and will update the correct value on select. You should also not use the index for the key for the menus.